# Is there a card that makes an enemy play my spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm an amateur player in Magic: The Gathering (Modern format) and I was looking for a card that makes an enemy play a spell from my hand.
For example if I had a "Discard your hand" card I could make him play that as if it was him (making him pay the mana cost or not).

I'm aware [Hive Mind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hive%20Mind) enchantement exists; are there any other cards with a similar effect?

Thank you

Comment: Mindslaver is somewhat similar.

Comment: @beam022, That acronym sounds corny.

Answer (score 4):

Hive Mind is definitely the simplest. Apart from that, there are other ways but they're a lot more convoluted. Things like:

- Put your [One with Nothing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=One%20with%20Nothing) on an [Isochron Scepter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Isochron%20Scepter). [Donate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Donate) the scepter, then [Mindslaver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindslaver) your opponent and make them cast it.
- Put [One with Nothing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=One%20with%20Nothing) on top of your library (perhaps with [Brainstorm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brainstorm) or [Insidious Dreams](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Insidious%20Dreams)), then cast [Knowledge Pool](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knowledge%20Pool). Then use [Mindslaver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindslaver) and have them cast any spell, and choose to turn it into [One with Nothing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=One%20with%20Nothing).

There are a couple of other ways that are just as complicated.

Comment: Do you mean Knowledge Pool instead of Omen Machine?

Comment: +1 for the 4 card Mirrodin-Donate combo that only raises the question, "Wouldn't a Pact have been simpler?"

Comment: @diego: Oops, yes I did! Answering from memory without checking rules text - always a bad plan.

Comment: @deworde: Indeed - the example given just gets you Wit's End at a 6 mana discount, but an off-colour Pact works just as well and is a lot more evil.

Comment: Shared Fate could also do the trick instead of Knowledge Pool :)